# what standard says about static casting to temporary inheritor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, standards, undefined-behavior

sometimes (quite rarely) I need to get protected members from existing variables
like this:

```
struct S {
protected:
 int i;
};

struct T : S {
 using S::i;
};

int main() {
 S s;
 static_cast<T&>(s).i = 0;
}
```

I'm almost sure this  ( static_cast(s) )  is UB, but is someone know what the C++ standard (2003) says about this situation?

Comment: If you need those variable outside of the class, then why are they protected in the first place?

Comment: This may break strict aliasing rule. But don't know if it's UB always.

Comment: "If you need those variable outside of the class, then why are they protected in the first place?" - the first class (and the variable of this class) is from another library, I can't change it's sources, only read and compile

Comment: Changing the visibility doesn't break the ABI AFAIK, so even if you don't have the source, you can monkey-patch the headers.

Comment: And why not add public accessors to i in T? Anyway, not a really good design when you have to directly modify attributes of a parent class.

Comment: it's just an example... the class names are not the best either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of operation is actually the basis for implementing the constant reoccurring template pattern, where inside the base-class you actually `static_cast` the `this` pointer of the base-class to the derived-class template type.  Since `S` is an unambiguous base class of `T`, and you are not accessing any members from the `static_cast` that are not already members of `S`, I don't see why you would encounter any issues.

Section 5.2.8 on static casting in paragraph 5 states:

> An lvalue of type “*cv1* B”, where B is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to *cv2* D”, where D is a class derived (clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10), *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and B is not a virtual base class of D. The result is an lvalue of type “*cv2* D.” If the lvalue of type “*cv1* B” is actually a sub-object of an object of type D, the lvalue refers to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.

You seem to be meeting all the requirements that avoid undefined behavior.  That is:

1. Class `T` is derived from `S`
2. A pointer conversion from `S` to `T` does exist since `S` is both accessible and an unambiguous base-class of `T` (requirements from 4.10)
3. You are using the same constant-value-qualification for both types
4. `S` is not a virtual base-class of `T`

Comment: I've never understood the ability of static_cast to cast to a more derived type. In this case it's clear that `s` *is not* a `T`, which could be easily demonstrated by adding another member variable to `T`.

Comment: You can make the cast, but accessing a non-existent member is going to invoke undefined behavior.  I believe in this regard it's pretty-much trying to mirror C-style casting, where you can cast from any pointer type to any other pointer type.  The results of the cast itself are not undefined, but trying to access a non-existent `struct` member in the cast pointer for instance would result in undefined behavior.